# calling a C function using cocoa

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a C function with the following method signature.

```
NSString* md5( NSString *str )
```

How do I call this function, pass in a string, and save the returned string?

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
NSString *temp= [[NSString alloc]initWithString:md5(password)];
```

thanks for your help

Comment: That code looks fine, assuming password is an NSString variable. You're going to need to provide more details. How did it "not work"? Where does password come from?

Comment: May help to indicate what exactly didn't work.  Did the compiler give an error?  What was the error?  What happens if you try NSString *a = md5(password); NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:a];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making it too hard.  The stuff in `[]`'s is effectively smalltalk.  What you want is to just call the function in C:

```
NSString * temp = md5(password);
```

Comment: temp = [md5(password) copy] or [md5(password) retain] may be needed though

Comment: It's true they're making it too hard, but their code should work, as the comments on the question suggest.

Question is bad and needs more details.

Comment: yeah, but "making it too hard" is usually a sign they don't understand what they're trying to do.  Agree more details might help.

Answer (score 0):

What is password? Is password a common "char *" pointer? Is the **md5** signature you put correct?

If that's the case, you could:

```
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:password  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

If your md5 signature is: char *md5(char *password), and you have you password stored in a NSString, you could:

```
NSString password = @"mypass";
char buff[128];
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:password];
[temp getCString:buff maxLength:128 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
char *md5 = md5(buff);
// then you could do whatever you want with md5 var
```